# Pra que servem os arquivos com extensão "sock"?

Tags: linux, socket

Algumas aplicações, como PHP-FPM e MYSQL, costumam utilizar em suas configurações um arquivo com a extensão `.sock`.

Eu sempre vejo isso em sistemas operacionais Linux.

Exemplo:

```
 /var/run/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Até onde eu entendi ele está relacionado com conexão socket.

Eu queria saber qual é o propósito desse arquivo `sock`.

A minha outra curiosidade é: Usando ele, não é necessário abrir uma 
porta para conexões socket? O arquivo com extensão `sock` por si só seria a conexão?

Answer (score 1):

> Para conexões externas sim, mas isso tem que ser feito pelo software dono do socket.

Soquetes são pontos de comunicação nos mesmos ou diferentes computadores para trocar dados. Eles são suportados por Unix, Linux, BSDs, Windows, Mac outros.
É uma comunicação mais rápida e eficiente que TCP/IP.

Além de enviar dados, os processos podem enviar descritores de arquivos em uma conexão de soquete de domínio Unix usando as chamadas de sistema **sendmsg()** e **recvmsg()**. Isso permite que os processos de envio concedam acesso ao processo de recebimento a um descritor de arquivo para o qual o processo de recebimento de outra forma não tenha acesso.